# Prevent flex items from stretching

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Sample:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background: tan;
}
span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This is some text.</span>
</div>
```

I have two questions, please:

1. Why does it basically happen to the `span`?
2. What is the right approach to prevent it from stretching without affecting other flex items in a flex container?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

You don't want to stretch the span in height?
You have the possiblity to affect one or more flex-items to don't stretch the full height of the container.

***To affect all flex-items of the container, choose this:***
You have to set `align-items: flex-start;` to `div` and all flex-items of this container get the height of their content.

```css
div {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: tan;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}
span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This is some text.</span>
</div>
```

***To affect only a single flex-item, choose this:***
If you want to unstretch a single flex-item on the container, you have to set `align-self: flex-start;` to this flex-item. All other flex-items of the container aren't affected.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background: tan;
}
span.only {
  background: red;
  align-self:flex-start;
}
span {
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="only">This is some text.</span>
  <span>This is more text.</span>
</div>
```

**Why is this happening to the `span`?**
The default value of the property `align-items` is `stretch`. This is the reason why the `span` fill the height of the `div`.

**Difference between `baseline` and `flex-start`?**
If you have some text on the flex-items, with different font-sizes, you can use the baseline of the first line to place the flex-item vertically. A flex-item with a smaller font-size have some space between the container and itself at top. With `flex-start` the flex-item will be set to the top of the container (without space).

```css
div {
  align-items: baseline;
  background: tan;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}
span {
  background: red;
}
span.fontsize {
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="fontsize">This is some text.</span>
  <span>This is more text.</span>
</div>
```

> You can find more information about the difference between `baseline` and `flex-start` here:
>   **[What's the difference between flex-start and baseline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34606879/3597276)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it affects all flex items. And a question: what is the difference between `baseline` and `flex-start` values? Their results seem to be the same. Can they be different in a situation?

Comment: Seems great! I'd be grateful if you'd tell me the difference between the `baseline` and `flex-start` values, too.

Comment: [What's the difference between `baseline` and `flex-start`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34606879/3597276)

Comment: Tip: If you want to align them horizontally, just use `align-items: center;` :)

Comment: #Hack : Wrap your element  with a new div. This will strech the new parent div and leave your element untouched.

Comment: This is the exact answer I needed thank you so much!

Comment: Doesn't work for `column` direction

Answer (score 7):

Sebastian Brosch has already given a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887124/478018). Here's an alternative approach:
`margin-bottom: auto`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background: tan;
}

span {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This is some text.</span>
</div>
```