# How to make flexbox child's height to fit to content instead of 100% height of its container

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
#container {
  display:flex;
  height:300px;
  background:#333;
}
#child1 {
  width:30%;
  background:#3cf;
}
#child2 {
  width:30%;
  background:#3fc;
}
#child3 {
  width:40%;
  background:#cf3;
}
#child1_child {
  width:100%;
  background:#fc3;
}
pre {
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
    <div id="child1"><div id="child1_child"><pre>CONTENT<BR>CONTENT<BR>CONTENT<BR>CONTENT</pre></div></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
    </div>
```

The height of `#child1` is automatically set to the same height of `#container`, How can I make it to fit to `#child1_child` rather than 100% height of `#container`?

The height of `#child1_child` is not static, it can be changed by content inside of it, height of `#child1` with static value is useless.

Comment: possibly related: [**How to disable equal height columns in Flexbox**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33043084/3597276)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fit-content` is limited in support; IE won't ever support it, and Firefox still requires a prefix. This solution has jQuery for demo purposes only and is not required for the solution. There are four choices:

> 1. **NONE:** No extra styles on `.A`
> 2. **FIT-CONTENT:** Adds the CSS property `fit-content` on `.A`
> 3. **MAX-CONTENT:** Adds the CSS property `max-content` on `.A`
> 4. **TABLE:** Adds the CSS property `display:table` on `.A`

Option 2 and 3 behave identically , so in conclusion the simplest solution is to apply `display:table` and it's incredibly compatible as it is simple. `height: fit-content` and `max-content` is almost as compatible with one minor caveat being that IE does not support it (IE is going the way of the dinosaur so it's pretty much a non issue).

---

#### Demo

```js
$('.rad').on('change', switchStyle);

function switchStyle(e) {
  var pick = $(this).val();
  switch (pick) {
    case 'nil':
      $('.A').removeClass('fit max tab');
      break;
    case 'fit':
      $('.A').addClass('fit').removeClass('max tab');
      break;
    case 'max':
      $('.A').addClass('max').removeClass('fit tab');
      break;      
    case 'tab':
      $('.A').addClass('tab').removeClass('fit max');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  background: #333;
}
.A {
  width: 30%;
  background: #3cf;
}
.B {
  width: 30%;
  background: #3fc;
}
.C {
  width: 40%;
  background: #cf3;
}
.A1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fc3;
}
pre {
  margin: 0px;
}
.set {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 300px;
  left: 30%;
  width: 30ch;
  font: 400 16px/1.428 Verdana;
}
.A.fit {
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -fit-content;
}
.A.max {
  height: max-content;
}
.A.tab {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="A1"><pre>
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT
    CONTENT</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
</div>

<fieldset class='set'>
  <label>NONE
    <input class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value='nil' checked>
  </label>
  <label>FIT-CONTENT
    <input class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value='fit'>
  </label><br>
  <label>MAX-CONTENT
    <input class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value='max'>
  </label>  
  <label>TABLE
    <input class='rad' name='rad' type='radio' value='tab'>
  </label>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `height: fit-content` is an experimental feature as of 2017 and shouldn't be used in production. For example, current Firefox doesn't support it. But Chrome does.

Comment: @Updated, sir. Please inform me of any discrepancies.

Answer (score 17):

Try setting `min-height` or `min-width`... Magic.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

By default, flex items won’t shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element). To change this, set the min-width or min-height property. (See §4.5 Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items.)
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex

Comment: OMG, great, it works!

Answer (score 10):

Using of experimental values of the `height` CSS property is generally discouraged.

If it is individual `flex`box child which you want to fill the height according to its content, use `align-self: baseline;` for it (see the example). If it is all the children, put `align-items: baseline;` into the parent container.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  background: #333;
}

#child1 {
  width: 30%;
  background: #3cf;
  align-self: baseline;
}

#child2 {
  width: 30%;
  background: #3fc;
}

#child3 {
  width: 40%;
  background: #cf3;
}

#child1_child {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fc3;
}

pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
    <div id="child1"><div id="child1_child"><pre>CONTENT<BR>CONTENT<BR>CONTENT<BR>CONTENT</pre></div></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't have to -1 my answer just because I did it to yours. Mine answers the OP clearly.

Comment: Did I seem resentful to you when you pointed out that my original answer was not fully browser compatible? I updated my answer and mentioned that you are the one that pointed that out. Sorry you feel that way.

Comment: Well, I -1'd your answer's original version to point out that it doesn't actually answer the OP and has some serious downfalls. That's what  -1 button is for. You -1'd my perfectly working solution just to get my attention. Yeah, this looks kind of "resentful".

Comment: As you should -1, and I updated it. Answering a question and providing a solution aren't always one in the same thing. No, I don't need to get your attention, I needed you to see the update. You are the gentleman that brought it to my attention, correct? I'm not the only one that's been through this page, the OP already got 2 more votes.

Comment: I'm not a "gentleman that brings attention of others" giving out -1s. I just push -1 when I find serious discrepancies in the answers provided. Just like in this case.

Comment: No you didn't bring attention to "others" you brought it to me. I respected your downvote by accrediting you for pointing it out and then updating my answer with not only a working solution but an interactive demo as well.  Did you even bother to review the update? Look whatever dude, I didn't downvote you but you made up your mind anyways. Don't bother me, anymore, please.

Comment: Lol. If you get bothered by mere -1s, I politely suggest you to quit SO.

Comment: You are the one ranting I didn't even care about one point  I got 11k dude, read this thread. I even said that you should -1 me. Loss of a point isn't bothering me, it's you keep ranting, calm down. I'm leaving and I'll let you rant by yourself, good day.

Comment: Which I did exactly.

Comment: Worth noting that it's not specifically `baseline` that accomplishes it. For example, if you want it centered while still forming to content height then you can use `center` as the value.

Comment: Great answer, except you probably want to use `flex-start` and not `baseline`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611670/4642943