# Flexbox align-items: baseline works, but align-self: baseline doesn't. Why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I seem to be observing some confusing behavior with flexbox, specifically when attempting to use `align-self: baseline`. The basic issue is that it simply doesn’t work; the following snippet demonstrates the problem:

```css
.flex-form {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-form label {
  align-self: baseline;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="flex-form">
  <label>Label: </label>
  <input type="text" placeholder=" " />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here’s a screenshot of what the output looks like:

> [image]

As you can see, the label’s baseline is *not* aligned with the other form elements, despite having `align-self: baseline` set. If I use `align-items: baseline` on the parent container, however, I get a different result:

```css
.flex-form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="flex-form">
  <label>Label: </label>
  <input type="text" placeholder=" " />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> [image]

Is this correct behavior according to the spec, or is it a bug? If so, why? Is there a workaround? For reference, I’ve tested on Chrome 54, Safari 9.1.2, and Firefox 50 on macOS 10.11.6, and they all seem to exhibit the same results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution

If you want baseline alignment for all items, apply `align-self: baseline` to each or, more simply, set `align-items: baseline` on the container.

### Explanation

An initial setting of a flex container is `align-items: stretch`.

This means that all flex items will expand the full cross-axis length of the container.

That's what's happening in your layout. ***EXCEPT***, you've overridden `align-items: stretch` on one flex item (`label`), by applying `align-self: baseline`.

While the other flex items stretch, the label has a `baseline` instruction – but no point of reference.

*From the spec:*

> [**8.3. Cross-axis Alignment: the `align-items` and `align-self`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)
>
> **`baseline`**
>
> If the flex item’s inline axis is the same as the cross axis, this
>   value is identical to `flex-start`.
>
> Otherwise, it participates in baseline alignment: all participating
>   flex items on the line are aligned such that their baselines align,
>   and the item with the largest distance between its baseline and its
>   cross-start margin edge is placed flush against the cross-start edge
>   of the line.

Okay, let's break this down:

- The first line doesn't apply. In this case, the flex item's *inline axis* is the same as the main axis (horizontal), not the cross axis (vertical), so  `baseline` doesn't resolve to `flex-start`.
- *"...all participating flex items on the line are aligned such that their baselines align..."* Well, there's only one item with baseline alignment. There is no other baseline for reference. Apparently, the browser falls back to `flex-start` in such a scenario (but I haven't seen an official reference for this behavior).

The rest of the spec language is not relevant to this question, but is covered in detail in this related post: *[What's the difference between flex-start and baseline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34606879/3597276)*

Comment: Ah, I see, this makes sense, since if I put `align-self: baseline` on *both* the label and the text field, their baselines are aligned. In retrospect, it seems obvious that an element’s baseline cannot be aligned to anything if there are no other elements to align its baseline to. ;) Thanks!