# text of input need to be more vertically aligned compared to other divs content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created some chips/tags with an input element next to them.

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/zZeERw

The vertical orientation of the text inside the chips is different to the vertical orientation of the text inside the input element."Enter new customer name" is a bit higher or more top aligned.

How can I fix this without using hacks like padding-top:3px...

I would like to normalize that text orientation in the input because it seems to me that the text inside the input itself is also not centered vertically within that input, or am I wrong?

How can I do that?

HTML

```
<div class="md-chips-component">
  <div class="md-chips-container" tabindex="-1">
     <div class="md-chips d-flex">
        <div class="md-chip">
          <div class="md-chip-text">Neil</div><div class="md-chip-remove">X</div>        
       </div>
        <div class="md-chip">
          <div class="md-chip-text">Strongman</div><div class="md-chip-remove">X</div>
       </div>        
       <form [formGroup]="schoolclassForm">
         <input class="md-chip-input" type="text" value="Enter new customer name" />
       </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="error-messages">
    <p>That field is required.</p>
    <p>Minimum are 3 chars.</p>
     <p>customer already exists.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.md-chip {
     display: flex;    
    letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
    color: #444;
    border-radius: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin: 0.1rem 0.3rem 0.1rem 0;
    padding: 0.08rem 1rem;

    line-height: 34px;
    background: #efefef;
    user-select: none;
     outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.md-chips-container
{
  padding-bottom:5px;
  border-bottom:2px solid #efefef;
}

.md-chips-container:focus
{
  border-bottom:2px solid #2196F3;
}

.md-chip-text{
  margin-right:10px;
}

.md-chip-input {
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0;
    background:transparent;
    outline:none;  
    border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
    padding-left:5px;   
    } 

.error-messages p
{
  margin-bottom:0px;
  color:red;
}

.md-chip:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this adjustment to your code:

```
.d-flex {
   display: flex;
   align-items: baseline; /* NEW */
}
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpJvxv?editors=1100)

More details here:

- [What's the difference between flex-start and baseline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34606879/3597276)
- [Flexbox align-items: baseline works, but align-self: baseline doesn't. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40727657/3597276)

Comment: In my latest chrome I can not see any difference in your revised codepen?

Comment: I tested it on Chrome and FF before posting the answer. It made a difference and lined up the text.

Comment: Just tested it at home where it works. Might be a older chrome version in the office ;-) Thanks Michael, align-items is the correct and only solution someone should accept here no margin/padding-top hacks.

Comment: Also works in Edge browser but in IE 11 the md-chip-input is just half the height of the chips, but this can be fixed with an explicit height:34px; same as line-height:34px; :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your css class .md-chip-input, try to achieve this by working on "padding-top"

```
`.md-chip-input {
    line-height: 34px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background:transparent;
    outline:none;
    border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
    padding-left:5px; 
    margin-top: 1px;
    }
```

`

I suggest also to add a small margin-top