# Why inside my bootstrap table td won't change height based on other td?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've got a page where is presented single article along with part where u can see info abou loan, based on articles price.

Now I've created bootstrap table, mapped through data, displayed them and everything is fine.

But problem that I got: I want to display additional data under bank name. Now when I do that, other three `td` won't change their height to stay in same line as first one.

Here is screenshot where everything is ok:
[image: ok table]

Now when I add two more things under bank:
[image: problem]

Now what I was expecting is that, these three right rows shift automatically down, and follow bank(auto adjust height to be same as height of columns in first row). So basically I was expecting result like this:
[image: desired]

Is there some way of fixing this?

Here is my Article.js component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Form from 'react-validation/build/form';
import Input from 'react-validation/build/input';
import CheckButton from 'react-validation/build/button';

import ArticleService from '../services/article.service';

const Article = (props) => {
  const form = useRef();
  const checkBtn = useRef();
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
  const [dataArr, setDataArr] = useState([]);

  const [months, setMonths] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onChangeMonths = (e) => {
    const months = e.target.value;
    setMonths(months);
  };

  const handleMonths = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setLoading(true);

    if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      try {
        const res = await ArticleService.article(id, months);
        setContent(res.data);
        const data = res.data.kredit;
        const dataArr = [];
        dataArr.push({
          name: 'kreditNKS-rataNKS',
          price: data.kreditNKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),
          rate: data.rataNKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),
          nks: data.stopaNKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),
          banka: {
            eks: data.stopaEKS.map((item) => {
              return item;
            }),

            bankname: data.ime.map((item) => {
              return item;
            }),

            type: data.tip.map((item) => {
              return item;
            }),
          },
        });
        setDataArr(dataArr);

        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      const res = await ArticleService.article(id);
      setContent(res.data);
      const data = res.data.kredit;
      const dataArr = [];
      dataArr.push({
        name: 'kreditNKS-rataNKS',
        price: data.kreditNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        rate: data.rataNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        nks: data.stopaNKS.map((item) => {
          return item;
        }),
        banka: {
          eks: data.stopaEKS.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),

          bankname: data.ime.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),

          type: data.tip.map((item) => {
            return item;
          }),
        },
      });
      setDataArr(dataArr);
    };
    fetchPosts();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const a = dataArr;

  const render = (item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>
          {item.banka.bankname.map((it, index2) => (
            <h4>
              {it}
              <br></br>                         //from here
              EKS: {item.banka.eks[index2]}     when i add this part, height dont change
              <br></br>
              Tip: {item.banka.type[index2]}   //to here
            </h4>
          ))}
        </td>
        <td>
          {item.nks.map((it) => (
            <h4>{it}</h4>
          ))}
        </td>
        <td>
          {item.price.map((it) => (
            <h4>{it}</h4>
          ))}
        </td>
        <td>
          {item.rate.map((it3) => (
            <h4>{it3}</h4>
          ))}
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p className='text-dark'>
        <Link to='/dashboard'>
          <i className='fas fa-arrow-left'></i> Nazad
        </Link>
      </p>
      <div className='container p-3 my-3 bg-dark text-white'>
        <strong>Artikal id:{content.id}</strong>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Opis:
            <br></br>
            {content.descr}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Cijena
            <br></br>
            {content.price}
          </div>
          <div className='col-sm'>
            Cijena po metru kvadratnom:
            <br></br>
            {content.ppm2}/m2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='container'>
        <h3>KREDITI ZA CIJENU {content.price}</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={handleMonths} ref={form}>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>Vrijeme otplate u mjesecima:</label>
            <Input
              type='text'
              className='form-control w-25'
              name='months'
              value={months}
              onChange={onChangeMonths}
            />

            <button
              className='btn btn-primary btn-block w-25'
              disabled={loading}
            >
              {loading && (
                <span className='spinner-border spinner-border-sm'></span>
              )}
              <span>Prikaži</span>
            </button>
            <CheckButton style={{ display: 'none' }} ref={checkBtn} />

            <small>
              Ako se ne unese vrijeme otplate kredita, kredit se izračunava za
              60 mjeseci
            </small>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>

      <div className='table-responsive'>
        <table className='table'>
          <thead className='thead-dark'>
            <tr>
              <th scope='col'>Informacije o banci</th>
              <th scope='col'>NKS</th>
              <th scope='col'>Ukupna cijena kredita</th>
              <th scope='col'>Mjesečna rata kredita</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{a.map(render)}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Article;
```

**EDIT:**

Also this is how my `a` look where I'm mapping for data:
[image: look of a]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try displaying the table data like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

var a = [
  { info: ['Ziraat', 'EKS', 'Tip'], nks: '4.11', total: '360090.95 KM', rata: '60001.52 KM/mi'  },
  { info: ['Ziraat', 'EKS', 'Tip'], nks: '3.94', total: '358594.45 KM', rata: '60001.52 KM/mi' },
  { info: ['UniCredit', 'EKS', 'Tip'], nks: '7', total: '386123.37 KM', rata: '60001.52 KM/mi' }
];

const Dashboard = () => {

  return (

    <table class="table text-center">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Info</th>
          <th scope="col">NKS</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
          <th scope="col">Rata</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {a && a.map((item) => (
          <tr key={item.id}>
            <td className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
              {item.info && item.info.map((index) => (
                <span>{index}</span>
              ))}
            </td>
            <td className="align-middle">{item.nks}</td>
            <td className="align-middle">{item.total}</td>
            <td className="align-middle">{item.rata}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>

  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

The above code results in the below output:

[image: Code Output]

---

**Updated Code:** For the `a` object that you provided.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

var a = [
  { bankname: ['ZiraatBank', 'ZiraatBank', 'UniCreditBank'], eks: ['6.24', '5.65', '8.26'], 
  name: 'kreditNKS-rataNKS', nks: ['4.11', '3.94', '7'], price: [107473.32, 107026.62, 115242.94], 
  rate: [1791.22, 1783.78, 1920.72], type: ['Fiksna', 'Promjenjiva', 'Fiksna']  },
];

const Dashboard = () => {

  return (

    <table class="table text-center">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Info</th>
          <th scope="col">NKS</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
          <th scope="col">Rata</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {a[0].bankname && a[0].bankname.map((item, i) => (
          <tr>
            <td className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                <span>{item}</span>
                <span>EKS: {a[0].eks[i]}</span>
                <span>Tip: {a[0].type[i]}</span>
            </td>
            <td className="align-middle">{a[0].nks[i]}</td>
            <td className="align-middle">{a[0].price[i]}</td>
            <td className="align-middle">{a[0].rate[i]}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>

  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Output for this new code:

[image: Code Output]

Comment: [link](https://prnt.sc/xps3ib) This is how my `a` looks like. I've tried in your way by mapping `item.bankaname`, `item.nks` etc. but it gives me output like this: [link](https://prnt.sc/xpsd9i)

Comment: ok I think the links you provided aren't working correctly... You can just provide one or two items from the **a** list then I'll check

Comment: [link](https://easyupload.io/m/ketfwm) Can you access this link?

Comment: No it says access denied

Comment: i've added it into the post, since you can't access the links.

Comment: ok. Looking at the `a` object, I've updated the solution.

Comment: Yep. Works. Just needed to put `{a[0] && a[0].bankname.map((item, i) => ` because it was throwing an error `bankname undefined`. Big claps my dude. Thanks so much!

Comment: Ok That's great