# Stop flex child from being full width

Tags: css, flexbox

I've created a row of items and made their heights match using flex. However this is causing my link within the items to become full width, when I just want it to be an automatic width. I've tried setting it to `display: inline-block` but this hasn't fixed it.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v0o2z9g3/2/

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; }

  .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    margin: 0 19px 65px;
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 38px);
    background: red; }
    .col .resource-item__title {
      font-weight: bolder; }
      .col .resource-item__summary {
        margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
        .col .resource-item__link {
          display: inline-block;
          background: yellow;
          margin-top: auto; }
          .col .resource-item__icon {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-right: 5px;
            color: green;
            font-size: 22px;
            cursor: default; }
            .col .resource-item__icon.disabledIcon {
              color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">view</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">Download</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far sadsa das das das das dfar away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia hgghk hkj hkljand Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">Download</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I basically require the yellow block to end where the the text ends, rather than stretching to the container edges.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply set `align-self: flex-start` to the class `.resource-item__link`. In this solution the hyperlink elements (`<a>`) are all on the same level and not placed directly under the content of each column (`.col`).

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  margin: 0 19px 65px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 38px);
  background: red; 
}
.col .resource-item__title {
  font-weight: bolder; 
}
.col .resource-item__summary {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
.col .resource-item__link {
  align-self:flex-start;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: auto;
}
.col .resource-item__icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: default;
}
.col .resource-item__icon.disabledIcon {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">view</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">Download</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far sadsa das das das das dfar away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia hgghk hkj hkljand Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">Download</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Also have a look at these questions:**

- [Make flex items take content width, not width of parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141163/make-flex-items-take-content-width-not-width-of-parent-container)
- [Prevent flex items from stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887051/prevent-flex-items-from-stretching)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:flex;flex-direction:column;` from `.col`. To make them equal heights you only need `.row` to be `display:flex;`.

Here's upadated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0o2z9g3/3/)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; }

  .col {
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    margin: 0 19px 65px;
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 38px);
    background: red; }
    .col .resource-item__title {
      font-weight: bolder; }
      .col .resource-item__summary {
        margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
        .col .resource-item__link {
          display: inline-block;
          background: yellow;
          margin-top: auto; }
          .col .resource-item__icon {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-right: 5px;
            color: green;
            font-size: 22px;
            cursor: default; }
            .col .resource-item__icon.disabledIcon {
              color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">view</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">Download</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h4 class="resource-item__title">Shale Gas Briefing Final</h4>
    <p class="resource-item__summary">Far sadsa das das das das dfar away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia hgghk hkj hkljand Consonantia, there live ...</p>
    <a class="resource-item__link" href="test-page-/114954ad-b674-4ad7-b90c-00e26bad10ed">Download</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added it already.

Comment: Sorry, I needed that so that I could align the buttons to the bottom of the containers